# How to prevent multiple event listeners being added with jquery and socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I have a function that sets up a listener on $('.message-input')

```
function addEasterEgg(room){
  $('.message-input').on('focus', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('room', room)
    if (room.length === 1) {
      displayStatus("No-one's there!!")
    };
  });
}
```

It's called on the event roomStatus.

```
socket.on('roomStatus', function(room){
  addEasterEgg(room);
});
```

The roomStatus event is triggered each time someone joins the room. So if the room has 1 person first, it is triggered and room = ["Zf17x3UsNUdgMJ3UAAAD"] then when another person joins, it is triggered again and room = ["Zf17x3UsNUdgMJ3UAAAD", "ksxzbQhe0GuZqhMyAAAE"]

So on the 'focus' event, I get two console.logs (one for each room value) and room.length always equals 1 even if it has since become 2

I believe it's because my method is called twice meaning 2 listeners are added. If that's right, how should I manage removing the previous listener when the roomStatus is next called and addEasterEgg is called?

Thanks

Comment: Is your 'on' function wrapped by a 'while' or 'for' loop?

Comment: just delegate the listeners once outside of the callback. Since it doesn't appear the callback is doing any DOM insertion you may not even need delegation

Answer (score 6):

I found the fix. It looks like it was indeed adding multiple event listeners to

```
$('.message-input')
```

So simply removing any remaining event listeners before adding fixed it

```
$('.message-input').off('focus')
```

added to:

```
function addEasterEgg(room){
  $('.message-input').on('focus', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('room', room)
    if (room.length === 1) {
      displayStatus("No-one's there!!")
    };
  });
}
```